# paginación con GridView

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, gridview

Necesito habilitar la paginación en una gridview con `Aspnet` y `visual Studio 2015`
Me carga la `gridview` con los datos correspondientes y 5 paginas.
Pero cuando doy click en la pagina 2 me envía el siguiente mensaje:

> ***Detalles de la excepción: System.InvalidOperationException: No se ha inicializado la propiedad ConnectionString.***

Detalles:

Tengo habilitada la paginación:

```
AllowPaging="True"
```

Cargo los datos en la grilla en el evento load de la pagina:

```
consultasql_Resumen.ConnectionString = CadenaConexion
```

El código en el evento correspondiente es el siguiente:

```
Private Sub GridResumen_PageIndexChanging(sender As Object, e As GridViewPageEventArgs) Handles GridResumen.PageIndexChanging  
   Me.GridResumen.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex  
   GridResumen.DataBind()  
    End Sub
```

Comment: estas uniendo el grid a un SqlDataSource ?

Comment: Si,   pero ya descubri la forma de hacerlo...    por si alguien tiene el mismo problema esta es la forma en que se puede obtener el valor de un buttonField en una GridView usando Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Si @LeandroTuttini,   pero ya descubri la forma de hacerlo...    
por si alguien tiene el mismo problema esta es la forma   
en que se puede obtener el valor de un buttonField en una GridView  
usando Visual Studio 2015.  
  
En la función RowCommand.  
  
Dim datos As LinkButton = TryCast(GridResumen.Rows(e.CommandArgument).Cells(8).Controls(0), LinkButton)  
ParamCorrCarga.Text = datos.Text

Answer (score 0):

> Respuesta escrita por el autor de la pregunta en los [comentarios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/17821/paginaci%C3%B3n-con-gridview#comment29313_17821)

Por si alguien tiene el mismo problema, ésta es la forma en que se puede obtener el valor de un `buttonField` en una `GridView` usando Visual Studio 2015.

En la función `RowCommand`:

```
Dim datos As LinkButton = TryCast(GridResumen.Rows(e.CommandArgument).Cells(8).Controls(0), LinkButton)  
ParamCorrCarga.Text = datos.Text
```